# Jersey StreamingOutput causing OOM Exception

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, jersey, out-of-memory

When using jersey, I am encountering an OOM exception serving large files. I thought that by using `StreamingOutput`, I would avoid keeping the entire file in memory and therefore avoid an OOM exception, but that doesn't seem to be the case. This is how we are building the `StreamingOutput`:

```
StreamingOutput streamingOutput = new StreamingOutput() {
                @Override
                public void write(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
                    final InputStream is = tis.getInputStream();
                    byte[] bbuf = new byte[1024 * 8];
                    long total = 0;
                    int length;
                    while ((is != null) && ((length = is.read(bbuf)) != -1)) {
                        outputStream.write(bbuf, 0, length);
                        total += length;
                        log.trace("Copied {} of {}", total, tis.getFileLength());
                    }
                    outputStream.flush();
                    is.close();
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            };

            responseBuilder = Response.ok(streamingOutput, tis.getStreamType());
```

tis is a typedInputStream...

Am I just mistaken in thinking that this should prevent the entire file from being in memory? I am using tomcat 7. I have about a gig of free heap, so when I try to download a 1.5 gig file, an OOM exception is thrown. Is there a mistake in this code? Looking at the heap dump, it seems all of the memory is being used by a byte array, I'm not sure if I can use the heap dump to figure out exactly where in the code that byte array is being initialized.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a filter that would buffer all the output?

Comment: That could be it, definitely...